# How to backup Telegram secret chats?

Tags: telegram

How can I make a private, complete backup of my Telegram chats *including* the secret chats?

---

I'm about to repair my iOS device which can likely result in factory reset. After repair, it will be still the same physical device, and I'll have a complete iTunes backup of it anyway.

If not possible, how can I export/save history of my secret chat(s) which were started on my iOS device?

Is there any better way of saving than making screenshots? (which is a tedious process, given the size of the history).

I'm using Telegram X client for iOS. I know it's discontinued, but my entire secret chat history is bound to it now.

Comment: @ale The app is both on web and on iOS / Android. Alternatively please move it to "Ask Different" StackExchange.

Comment: Too old to migrate. If there's a web component, I'll withdraw my close vote. That said, you'll probably get a better response at [apple.se].

Comment: @ale Surely there is, https://web.telegram.org/

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, there's no way to backup secret chats specifically. The rest, as you know, can be backed up and exported. But secret chats are bound to the device so they'll be gone once you reinstall the app. Even screenshots might not work as they come out blank in some cases (to keep the secret chat, well, secret.) It's a sacrifice for the sake of extra security.